# Playing built in sounds on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, audio, core-audio

I have an app that has a fake SMS screen, when this is displayed I want to play one of the SMS sounds that are on the phone.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SysSound is good sample code for playing sound, but you need to provide your own sound files.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to find the audio file and play it from your app. There's no SDK hook to make the notification sound play.